# How to set the updated text value of button throughout the app

Tags: flutter, button, text

I want to set the updated text value of button throughout the app, when i click on button its text changes to current time, but when I navigate to other screen, and then come back to the screen where I created a button, it is not showing the updated text.

here is my button widget

```
 String getTime;

//from here i get the current time 
void _getTime() {
    final String formattedDateTime =
        DateFormat('kk:mm:ss a').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
    setState(() {
      getTime = formattedDateTime;
      print("time");
      print(getTime);
    });
  }

 String timeInText = "Time in";

 Widget _timein() {
    //enable- initial case
    bool firstCaseFlag = true;
  

    if (getTimeInStatus == false && timeInButtonPressed == true) {
      print("i1");
      return FlatButton(
          color: timeInButtonPressed ? Colors.blue[500] : Colors.blue[200],
          textColor: Colors.white,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(buttonRoundRadius)),
          child: Row(children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.timer,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                timeInText,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: textFontSize),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
          onPressed: () {
            _getTime();
            setState(() {
              if (firstCaseFlag == true) {
                
                timeInText = getTime; //here i set the button text to current time
                timeIn = timeInText;
               
                firstCaseFlag = false;
              } else {
                
              }
            });
            calltimeInApi();
          });
```

**Conditions:**

There are certain conditions where button will change there state, like i have 2 button namely timein and timeout, initially timein button will be enable to click and timeout will be disable, so if user click on timein button its text change to current time and timeout button will be enable (this is all happening), and if user moved to other screen and come to home screen (where i created timein and timeout buttons) then timein button text should display that time when user click on it.

**Problem:**

My problem is when I moved to other screen and come to home screen timein button is enabled and not showing the time when i click on it.

please help how i can fix it.

Comment: basically you want to preserve the state of button ?

Comment: yes, but it will change also according to conditions too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using statemanagement `StateProvider`. here is an example just using `global variable`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:stack_overflow/exports.dart';

String buttonText = "Click to set";
///for riverpod
///final buttonState = StateProvider((ref) => "Click to set");

class BaseWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const BaseWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BaseWidgetState createState() => _BaseWidgetState();
}

class _BaseWidgetState extends State<BaseWidget> {
  void _getTime() {
    final String formattedDateTime =
        DateFormat('kk:mm:ss a').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
    setState(() {
      buttonText = formattedDateTime;
      print("time");
      print(buttonText);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _getTime();
            },
            child: Text(buttonText),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => NextWidget(),
              ));
            },
            child: Text("next"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const NextWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
        child: Text("Back"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, i am getting this error ```Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.``` at this line  ```final buttonState = StateProvider((ref) => "Click to set");```

Comment: you can remove that line, that is `riverpod` solution. the one i said about `statemanagement`

Answer (score 1):

Use state management like `Provider` to keep the values and then access anywhere.

Package link: https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Helpful reference: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro

Comment: i don't want to access the value in other screen, I just want to keep the updated value when i come back to the screen again!

Comment: Provider will keep it for you and just use it on that screen. I recommend reading about state management to get a little bit of knowledge around.